# html align text with value in a line

Tags: html, text-alignment

I'm creating a simple fake forum for a class project. It works exactly like a normal forum where you can post topics, comment, ect.. But when you are at the main forum page (bellow) there is text that says `signed in as` and then your `username` but the username is not right next to the text on one line like i want it to be. How can I merge them together?

[image: img]

This is the code for that line

```
<form align="right" id="name_disp">
    <div>
        <p id="SIA">signed in as </p>
        <a style="color:blue"id="userNAME" onclick="showProfile(this.innerHTML)">hahn2014</a>
        <input type="button" value="Sign Out" onClick="logOut()" style="width: 65px; height: 25px">
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: dont use <p>.. use <span>...

Comment: how bout put that `<a>...</a>` into `<p>signed in as <a>...</a></p>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `<p> </p>` use `<span></span>` like this :

```
<span id="SIA">signed in as </span>
<a style="color:blue"id="userNAME" onclick="showProfile(this.innerHTML)">hahn2014</a>
```

JSFIDDLE : http://jsfiddle.net/y9Gje/